# User account not appearing in setting or login screen

Tags: 20.04, gnome, login, partial-upgrade

After a partial upgrade, I was presented with gnome initial setup where I was forced to create a new user. With this new user I noticed the my old user was not gone, it was just not appearing on the list of users I can log in with, or in the system settings.

I did a bit of digging and found, `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` and my user was set to `SystemAccount=true`, changing that and logout, made it show on the login screen, and gnome settings. But whenever I reboot or shutdown, it is reset to `SystemAccount=true`.

I am not sure what to do to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Additional info:
Ubuntu 20.04.2
Gnome 3.36.8
GDM3
Nvidia driver 460.80

Comment: What is your original user's numerical UID (ex. output of `id -u` command or `getent passwd <username>`)?

Comment: `id -u` gives 1000 and `getent passwd <username>` gives `thomas:x:1000:1000:Thomas Chapados Muermans,,,:/home/thomas:/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: OK thanks so we can likely rule out UID_MIN / SYS_UID_MAX issues

Comment: Never do partial upgrades. It almost always breaks your system. Best/fastest to just reinstall Ubuntu... my opinion.

Comment: @heynnema yeah I figured it would mess something up, which is why I push it back, but it got annoying. And I can't really nuke an pave, it would be too much work to get it set up again.